# qtableview add and display ordered items as they arrive arbitrary?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I want to display a set of ordered items 1:N according to their ordering, as they arrive arbitrary, for example suppose the following items arrived in the following order:

#1,#2,#10
then the `Qtableview` should display them in the correct order without empty rows for the yet to arrive elements:

```
+------+
-  #1  -
-  #2  -
-  #10 -
+------+
```

if then #5 arrived the `qtableview` updates it's view to the following:

```
+------+
-  #1  -
-  #2  -
-  #5  -
-  #10 -
+------+
```

and so on.

How can I achieve such behavior with the best performance (without reordering and redrawing the entire data each time an item arrives)?

Comment: You probably want to look at [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit from QSortFilterProxyModel and possible redefine virtual function 
[lessThan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan)
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan